# target= _blank is Follow or NoFollow

Tags: javascript, web

target= _blank Link is DoFollow Or NoFollow.

This is the code:

```
<a href="https://pcgames_free.net" target="_blank">pc games Download</a>
```

Comment: You didn’t say `nofollow` so it’s not `nofollow`. Also don’t use `target="_blank"`; it’s annoying and suffers from https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google Website</a>

<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="dofollow">Google Website</a>
```

The attribute rel="dofollow" will do the same as if you have nothing.